# Animated banner launching full window overlay with video with third party components

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am relatively new to this sort of thing in Flash so I am really sorry if my explanation is lacking in any areas, and I would really appreciate if any answers could explain fully what I am doing so I can learn as opposed to just pasting in a solution.

What I am trying to produce is a small animated banner that when clicked will launch a semi-transparent overlay (similar to LightBox, initially this was built with LightBox in mind) covering the web page content and containing a video player. From now on I'm going to refer to these elements as 'banner' and 'overlay'. The overlay and the banner are contained in separate .swf files.

The banner is relatively complex, in that animates on loading, plays a looping animation while idle, and another animation on mouseOver. Clicking the banner or allowing the mouseOver animation to complete both launch the overlay. I had a working version that would call a jQuery Lightbox, but have now been asked to build that functionality in using other third party components and it has broken the animation and interactivity of the banner.

This is the ActionScript as it is in the banner file.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

curl_mc.alpha = 0;

curl_mc.stop();

hotspot_mc.useHandCursor = true;
hotspot_mc.buttonMode = true;

hotspot_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onLoopRollover, false, 0, true);
hotspot_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onLoopRollout, false, 0, true);

hotspot_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, screenad.shared.callMethod("launchLayer"));
curl_mc.addEventListener('curlComplete', screenad.shared.callMethod("launchLayer"));

function onLoopRollover(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  loop_mc.alpha = 0;
  loop_mc.stop();

  curl_mc.alpha = 1;
  curl_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

function onLoopRollout(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  loop_mc.alpha = 1;
  loop_mc.gotoAndPlay(1);

  curl_mc.alpha = 0;
  curl_mc.stop();
}
```

And here is the ActionScript in the overlay file.

```
screenad.hide();

screenad.shared.'showAd' = function()
{ 
  screenad.show;
}
```

These reflect the changes that were suggested to me by the support team of the components, but the animation in the banner is still broken as is the interactivity launching the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a mix of HTML + Flash to solve this problem.

What I probably would do is to have to separate flash objects.

The Banner and the Video.

The banner will a simple animated component once clicked, you can put an HTML overlay to the whole page and load the flash video component in it.

You can do the communication via flash -> Javascript via ExternalInterface class.

for example:

**AS3**

```
if( ExternalInterface.isAvailable )
{
    ExternalInterface.call("loadOverlayVideo","4")
}
```

Javascript

```
function loadOverlayVideo(videoId)
{
    showBlahBlah()
}
```

Note: If your functions are inside a JQuery embedded function you may need to "externalize" the function using:

```
window.loadOverlayVideo = loadOverlayVideo
```

Otherwise flash won't be able to find it

Please make sure you use configurable parameters on each function and you will obtain a really reusable component to use as many times as you want.

Hope it helps!